# Leetcode 203. Removed LinkedList elements

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I always have trouble understanding how the dummy/curr pointer updates the head pointer

The below code is the solution for the problem statement
**Given the head of a linked list and an integer val, remove all the nodes of the linked list that has Node.val == val, and return the new head.**

```
    public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        ListNode curr = head;

        while(curr != null && curr.val == val){
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        
        while(curr != null && curr.next != null){
            if(curr.next.val == val){
                curr.next = curr.next.next;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

The below code  fails for the case head = [7,7,7,7] , val = 7
Expected answer : [], Answer from the above code : [7,7,7,7]

the test case only gets into the first while loop where curr gets updated with its next pointer. I expected head also to be updated (head gets updated when the second while loop in execueted in other test cases) . Any explanation for this would be helpful

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What is the expected output of the `[7,7,7,7], val=7` test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never updates `head`, yet if the first node has the value to delete, then `head` will need to change... For the example list you provided, the function should even return null.

The first loop in your code should update `head`, not `curr`. `curr` only starts to play a role in the second loop:

```java
    public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        while(head != null && head.val == val){
            head = head.next;
        }
        
        ListNode curr = head;
        while(curr != null && curr.next != null){
            if(curr.next.val == val){
                curr.next = curr.next.next;
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: How is the second while loop updating the head node? In my code posted curr is set to head before the first while loop. So I was expecting the head to be updated as in how it happens in second while loop

Comment: If you don't ever *assign* to `head` then it will keep referencing the same node. Doing `curr = curr.next` will not influence `head`. If however `curr` is made equal to `head`, then assigning to `curr.next` (note the difference) in the second loop will change the chain that `head` indirectly references via the chained `next` references.